# How do you set UILayoutPriority?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've tried creating a reference to the constraint and then setting the Layout Priority but this makes the app crash

```
let topTrasactionConstraint = transactionsTableviewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsStackContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 6)


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topTrasactionConstraint,
            transactionsTableviewContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            transactionsTableviewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
            transactionsTableviewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
            ])


topTrasactionConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.init(999)
```

Comment: You can omit the `.init`, but this is correct and I don't see how that would cause a crash.  Perhaps you should post more details on the crash you are getting.

Comment: can you post the crash log i use it without a crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that I was calling

```
topTrasactionConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.init(999)
```

Before `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`
This was causing my application to crash

Answer (score 1):

How about `topTrasactionConstraint.priority = 999`?

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/easier-swift-layout-priorities/

Comment: This will not work. You can't assign an `Int` to type `UILayoutPriority`. The article you've linked manipulates the `rawValue` of the priority, not the priority directly.